# How to delete elements in a set from begining till one element before iterator using c++ stl?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, set, lower-bound

I have a `set` of `int`s as

```
set<int> ds;
ds.insert(2); 
ds.insert(3);
ds.insert(4);
ds.insert(5);
ds.insert(6);
ds.insert(7);
ds.insert(8);

set<int>::iterator it = lower_bound(ds.begin(), ds.end(), 6);
```

I want to delete 2 till 5.

I am currently trying to do like `ds.erase(ds.begin(), --it);`

But the code freezes and does not progress further. Also, I would not want to erase anything if there are no elements prior to the iterator location.

How to achieve it using c++ STL?

Comment: Do you really have `set<int>::iterator it = lower_bound(set.begin(), set.end(), 6);`?  The names don't match (`ds` vs `set`).  Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: changed set to ds.

Comment: `erase(a, b)` will not erase `b` it will erase *up to b*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you are.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

int main() 
{
    std::set<int> ds = { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

    ds.erase( ds.begin(), ds.lower_bound( 6 ) );

    for ( int x : ds ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
6 7 8
```

Or

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    std::set<int> ds = { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

    ds.erase( ds.begin(), std::lower_bound( ds.begin(), ds.end(), 6 ) );

    for ( int x : ds ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is the same as shown above.

Comment: Thanks. Probably I should make my concepts clear first. Didn't noticed about this range erase conditions.

Comment: What happends if there is no element to erase?

Comment: @user3243499 Nothing happens because the range is empty. Just use this call ds.erase( ds.begin(), std::lower_bound( ds.begin(), ds.end(), 2 ) ); in the demonstrative programs in my answer.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I just verified using your code. Got your point. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First `it` is pointing to `6` and `--it` changes  it `5`. In `std::map.erase(first, last)`

> Iterators specifying a range within the map container to be removed: [first,last). i.e., the range includes all the elements between first and last, including the element pointed by first but not the one pointed by last.Member types iterator and const_iterator are bidirectional iterator types that point to elements.

So you can simply use `it` instead  `--it`.

```
ds.erase(ds.begin(),it);
```